# Stripping WhiteSpace & Comments using python file executable from Command Line

Tags: python

Trying to write a program that takes in, from the command line, my executable file + an optional argument called 'no-comments' and the file.

So if someone writes in command line: stripWhiteSpace.py file.rtf
Then it will strip all the whitespace EXCEPT new lines.

If someone writes in command line: stripWhiteSpace.py no-comments file.rtf
Then it will strip all the whitespace except new lines, AND also remove all C/C++/Java style comments starting with "//" and anything that comes after that (that whole comment).

Here is my code (called stripWhiteSpace.py):

```
import sys
file = sys.argv[-1]

with open(file, 'r+') as f:
    final_file = ""
    if sys.argv[1] == "no-comments":
        for line in f:
            line = line.partition('//')[0]
            line = line.strip(' \t\r')
            final_file += line
    else:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip(' \t\r')
            final_file += line

    f.write(final_file)
```

The file is successfully passed through my python file. The problem is, it doesn't change. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you are using `strip()`. Doing `line.strip(' \t\r')` will strip only `' \t\r'` ie a space, followed by a tab, followed by a carriage return. I dont think that is going to happen very often. The syntax should be `line.strip([' ', '\t', '\r'])`.

Having said all that, if you are wanting to remove ALL white space, `strip` wont do that, it will only remove the white space at the start or end of the line. If you want to remove ALL the whitespace you need to use `.replace()`.